# Should I say "a week ago" or "a week before" or "a week earlier"?

Tags: grammar

She asked me while she was handing me the pathology report and trying to look relaxed.Her gynecologist took a uterine biopsy "a week before" and the results finally came out on this day.

Should I say "a week ago" or "a week before" or "a week earlier" ?

Comment: Although all 3 are correct, I suggest using "a week ago."

Comment: "A week ago" implies more strongly than the other two that it was 7 days ago.  The other two could be interpreted in multiple ways, including "during the week preceding the current" which could be anywhere from 3 to 10 days ago roughly.

Answer (score 3):

"A week ago" means "a week before *today*". If today is the 17th, and the biopsy was taken on the 10th, you should say that the biopsy was taken *a week ago*.

The phrase "a week before" usually means "a week before *that other event*". If you told me that the biopsy was taken "a week before", then I would probably wonder: it was taken a week before what?

The phrase "a week earlier" is similar to "a week before".

So, you should probably say "a week ago".

Comment: Yes, it all depends on when the present time is for the speaker or narrator. I often see this done incorrectly in movies: they write the intertitle as: a week ago. Very often, they actually mean: A week before.